# URDF tutorial robot falls

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I followed the [R2D2 URDF tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) and constructed a nice R2D2 robot. Now when I drive the robot, R2D2 tilts to his back. It is like his wheels have so much grip, that they run away under his body. I tried different configurations of mu1, mu2, kd, kp but none of it really worked.
Hope [this picture](https://imgur.com/YH9MiEH) makes my problem clear.
And here is my [URDF-File](https://pastebin.com/iTeXJkQ7)
Would be great if somebody has a hint, where to look at, or had a similar problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261699/urdf-tutorial-robot-falls/) by [Kaonashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30379/kaonashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial aims to show the basic workings of the interaction with Gazebo, and falls a bit short of presenting a usable robot model. You should be able to drive at a lower speed and have it not tip over. Best of luck.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kaonashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30379/kaonashi/) on 2017-05-16**:
Thanks for your reply. Do you have any recommendations for a tutorial of a "usable" model? Or any idea, how to make R2D2 usable?